# Not able to access Data inside Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI ,

```
 var jsonObj = [] ;

for (var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++) {

            jsonObj.push({id: data.jobs[i].Dater, optionValue: data.jobs[i].INCPU});
        }

alert(jsonObj);
```

I am getting as result as

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: Yes, you should tell what you expact to see instead

Comment: *[There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)*

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are alerting an array.  Trying alerting an individual index of that array.

```
alert(jsonObj[0])
```

Comment: which will output [object Object] ? :D

Comment: alert(jsonObj[0]) , this is outputing [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce a JSON serialisation, use a JSON parser library like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

The serialised form will also produce the expected result when you pass it to `alert()`.

Comment: @Marcelo This answer implies that JSON serialization can only be achieved with a separate library. This is of course not true, since all current browsers implement the [JSON global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: @Šime: That depends on what you define as current. If you want to support IE7, which still has about 10% of the market, then you'll run into trouble. Also, json2.js automatically falls back on the built-in JSON object, if present, so there is very little to be gained by avoiding it.

Comment: @Marcelo Let me repeat myself. Your answer implies that JSON serialization can only be achieved with a separate library. *"If you want feature X, add library Y to your web-page"* implies that library Y (or a similar library) is required for feature X. A more correct answer would be: *"If you want feature X, use function Y"* (`JSON.stringify()` in this case), and then *"Note: some older browsers (IE6, IE7, FF3 - ~20% of the market) don't implement this function. If you need to support those browsers, add library Z to your web-page"*.

Comment: @Šime: There was no need to repeat yourself; I understood you perfectly well the first time. In fact, it appears that it is you who failed to properly read what I wrote. My response to your comment was to the effect that, if you define IE7 as "current" — which I do, since 10% is still a very important segment of the market for most serious websites — then your claim that, "This is of course not true," is patently false. Moreover, you'll note that I never actually repudiated your first sentence.

Comment: If you really want to split hairs, my answer was either correct or it wasn't. If you can't point to anything I said that was false, then any talk of a "more correct" answer is dubious. My first statement was merely advice, which you can disagree with, but I note that in your suggested amended, you didn't suggest any change to the wording, merely an appended qualifier.

Comment: You could argue that my answer was incomplete, in which case, I quite agree — I had no intention of muddying the waters by pointing to facts about older browsers that had no material effect on the advice I was giving. You could also argue that it wasn't as helpful as it could have been, in which case, I would simply disagree. They are the only interpretations of "more correct" that come to mind just now.

Comment: @Marcelo Yes, I failed to clarify my wording - I decided to clarify the first sentence of my comment, and neglected the second one. The phrasing *"all current browsers"* is probably not the best one - *"the current versions of all (relevant) browsers"* would be more unambiguous. Therefore, I meant the set {IE9, FF4, Ch10, S5, O11}. To simplify this conversation, please let me revoke the second sentence of my initial comment. I still stand by my claim that your answer contains an incorrect implication. I believe I've provided an valid argument to back up this claim in my second response.

Comment: @Marcelo Yes, another poor choice of words from my side. The correctness of your answer is not in question. It's the implication of the first sentence of your answer that I'm trying to address here. I suggest this change of wording: *"If you want to produce a JSON serialization, use the `JSON.stringify()` function. Note: some older browsers (IE6, IE7, FF3) don't implement this function. If you need to support those browsers, you can use a JSON library like json2.js which will implement this function in those browsers."*.

Comment: @Šime: You are perfectly entitled to take that position, but it is not my position. I believe that web developers *should* use a library, because it is easy, painless and more robust, given the range of browsers out in the wild. If you believe otherwise, you are perfectly entitled to provide an alternate answer, which I note that you have done, but I also note that you haven't furnished any of the qualifiers you counselled me to supply. Which answer needs your proposed qualifiers more, the one that is guaranteed to work on almost all browsers, or the one that breaks on more than 10% of them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to achieve this:

```
var obj = [];

// populate obj in a loop

var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);

alert(jsonStr);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Smd2P/1/